# Adding more fields in MediaMetada GoogleCast

Tags: android, google-cast

When I cast Video from android phone to Chromecast device, I want to add additional fields for my own application. But when I get this field from the API (`VideoCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation()`). It always return null for String, zero for int.
Here I use another field is `MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST`:

```
MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, video.getFullName());
movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST, String.valueOf(video.getId()));// video ID
movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(video.getThumbnail())));

mSelectedMedia = new MediaInfo.Builder(link)
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .build();
mCastManager.loadMedia(mSelectedMedia, true, position);
```

But when I get this field, it always return null

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = mCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation();
MediaMetadata md = mediaInfo.getMetadata();
String title = md.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE));
String videoID = md.getString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST);// always return null;
```

It just works with these field: KEY_TITLE, KEY_STUDIO, KEY_SUBTITLE.
Can anyone explain this for me? Thanks.

P/S: For me, I guess MovieMetaDta( `MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)` ) class just has 3 above fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest for you would be to use the `customData` field on the `MediaInfo` object.